# Python Telegram bot keyboard

Tags: python, bots, telegram

i'm trying to do buttons,inline buttons,

```
json.dumps({"keyboard":[[{'text':'yayaya','request_contact':True},{'text':'google','url':'https://tts.ua'}]],})
```

First button wokrs, but other send only text, please help me

Comment: Please explain with which particular package you are using and a bit of code snippet.

Comment: I' m using requests
"""
    def send_message(self, chat_id, text,**kwargs):
        params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text}
        if 'buttons' in kwargs.keys():
            params['reply_markup'] = json.dumps({"keyboard":[[{'text':'yayaya','request_contact':True},{'text':'google','url':'https://google.com'}]],})
            print params
        method = 'sendMessage'
        resp = requests.post(self.api_url + method, params)
        return resp
"""

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup), which only supported [requests](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton).

But `url` is parameter of [inline_keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), you can't use both at the same time.